# ROS cv_bridge ImagePtr conversion in c++ string

Tags: c++, string, image-processing, mat

Below code snippet from ros subscriber node where video image frame is subscribed based on topic and displayed. As per my requirement  cv_ptr->image needs to be converted in to c++ string so that I can create byte array(vector )  out of that .

```
void imageCb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try
    {
      cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
    }

    if (cv_ptr->image.rows > 60 && cv_ptr->image.cols > 60)
      cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, cv::Point(50, 50), 10, CV_RGB(255,0,0));

    cv::imshow(WINDOW, cv_ptr->image);
    cv::waitKey(3);
}
```

basically I am looking for API which converts cv_ptr->image frame buffer  in c++ string .After subscribing image based on topic , I need to convert the same in byte array so that it can be inserted in activemqcpp producer as other end activemqjava subscriber is expecting the same in bytestream format.

```
string img_string = (copy operation) cv_ptr->image;// Not sure how to copy this buffer in c++ string

vector <unsigned char> vec(img_string.begin().img_string.end());
```

below is the class specification as per cv_bridge.h file.

```
class CvImage;
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<CvImage> CvImagePtr;
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<CvImage const> CvImageConstPtr;

 class CvImage
 {
 public:
 std_msgs::Header header; 
 std::string encoding;    
 cv::Mat image;           
 sensor_msgs::ImagePtr toImageMsg() const;

   void toImageMsg(sensor_msgs::Image& ros_image) const;

   typedef boost::shared_ptr<CvImage> Ptr;
   typedef boost::shared_ptr<CvImage const> ConstPtr;

};
```

Can anybody suggest how to achieve the same in roscpp?

Answer (score 0):

As specified here http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4d33bed1c850265370d2af0ff02e1564 OpenCV's Mat class already stores image data as unsigned char array.

The type of `cv_ptr->image` is already `cv::Mat`.

All you need to do access its contents like `cv_ptr->image.data`

Comment: you mean to say  : cv::Mat image = cv_ptr->image; string mystring (image.begin<unsigned char>(),image.end <unsigned char>());Now push_back the string in vector.

Comment: It's a regular array (but not a string, every char array is not a string!!) so you can directly access its elements and initialize the vector from there.

As you said cv::Mat already defines begin and end iterators and you can initialize a vector directly from the cv::Mat instance like:

```std::vector<unsigned char> my_vec(cv_ptr->image.begin(), cv_ptr->image.end());```

Comment: It gives compilation error as cv_ptr is a boost shared_ptr and it doesn't have begin and end method so i  don't have any option other than to create string separately and iterate inside vector.